# Removing a value in a specific row of a column without removing the entire row in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a csv that looks like this, the first A,B,C being the column headers:

```
A, B, C

A1,A2,A3
blah,B2,B3
C1,C2,C3
blahxxxxxtr,D4,D5
```

How do I remove the entries containing 'blah' or anything with 'blah' in them, without removing the whole rows.

Here is what is working so far:

```
import pandas as pd
file = r"\\fileserver\data\test.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   if 'blah' in str[row[0]:
        print(row['A']
        #this is where I don't know how to remove 'blah' if this is True
        #I want the new value of that to be a blank field, so  '',B2,B3
        #Same would go for the 4th row, '',D4,D5 
        # Using a drop command removes the whole row. 
df.to_csv(file, index = false)
```

This successfully prints the 2nd and 4th row of 'blah' values.
How do I remove and replace 'blah' with a blank string of '', so it does not have anything, not even Nan in that column for that specific row?

Comment: Try `df.replace('blah', '')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use replace.

```
df.replace(to_replace='blah', value='the value you want', inplace=True)
```

or if you want to replace a certain column value use

```
df[colname].replace(to_replace='blah', value='the value you want', inplace=True)
```

If inplace is set to true, the df will be updated internally. Else a df with changed value will be returned

Comment: Harsh, what if one of the rows looked like: blahfffff,B,C  - how do I ask to replace if it "contains" blah?

Comment: @MikeColeman `df.loc[df[colname].str.contains('blah'), colname] = ''`, where `colname` is your column name as string.